# TTL script controling the tool bar in Tera term

Tags: terminal, script

I am currently writing a TTL scrip, i want my scrip to be able to access the tera term tool bar go on the:
setup (tab) -> window setup -> (click the) background (box) -> (drag the) R bar to the most left -> (press) OK

I'm not even sure if this is able to be done in a ttl file, i'm hoping someone with more experience than me will be able to help me out

Answer (score 0):

This is not able to be done through a tera term script. 
However it can be done through IVT, IVT is very similar to tera term but IVT scripts are more powerful

Comment: This answer would be much better if you include a short example script.